# How to loop a specific block in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to loop the mail body so it keeps sending the email until <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is pressed. How do I do that?

```
 Mail.deliver do
   to 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
   from 'ada@test.lindsaar.net'
   subject 'testing sendmail'
   body 'testing sendmail' #how to loop the body to keep sending email
 end
```

Comment: Please read "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)". We'd like to see your attempt at solving the problem, along with a description of what didn't work. "[mcve]" discusses this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to start an infinite loop you can go with:

```
loop do
  # email sending logic here
end
```

Another option is:

```
while true
  # email sending logic here
end
```

Yet another one is:

```
until false
  # email sending logic here
end
```

You got the idea. Any of these will only stop when you stop it.

```
 loop do
  Mail.deliver do
    to 'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
    from 'ada@test.lindsaar.net'
    subject 'testing sendmail'
    body 'testing sendmail' #how to loop the body to keep sending email
  end
end
```

## EDIT

After the discussion in comments here is how you pass `body` as an argument:

```
def send_mail(body) # pass an argument called `body`
  Mail.deliver do
    to      'mikel@test.lindsaar.net'
    from    'ada@test.lindsaar.net'
    subject 'testing sendmail'
    body    body # use passed into the method argument
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
send_email('this is a demo body')
```

Comment: does not work bro i have already tried this , issue is the body is not sent until it meets the last end of Mail.deliver do , and when i add the loop do it gets between the body so it only loops the body and never meets the end

Comment: @noname I do not understand you. put the email sending code into the loop and you are good. Programming is programming, there is no such thing as `loop is not working`. It is.

Comment: i just want to loop the body and not the whole mail.deliver do ,if i loop the whole thing i wont be able to send the email with user input , i hope you understand what i am trying to say , if i loop the whole thing i have to stick with only one email but i need to make it so i can choose any email i want to send ... english is not my first language sorry

Comment: so you want the `body` to use the user's input? Why not just pass body as an argument and use it?

Comment: yes , if i loop the whole thing i wont get the option to choose whom i want to send each time i run the code or which email id do i want to use to send the mail.. that is why i only need to loop the body of the mail so each time i run the script i have a choice to whom i want to send etc.. can you please show me an example of passing the body as an argument ?

Comment: @noname see the edit. You can pass any number of arguments and use them inside the method as I showed with `body`

Comment: @noname glad to help :)

Comment: bro i am kind of stuck again , looping works fine if i have already set my email id ,subject etc from the script but when i use gets to get user input and try to loop `send_mail(gets)` it loops back to `def send_mail(body)` and then i have to enter everything again , i just want the body to loop , i tried calling new methods for each eg for subject etc but it does not work